# Como modificar la versión tools.builde.gradle para sincronizar gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

Tengo un problema y es que al ejecutar el siguiente código me da error

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
            android:text="Iniciar seción"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
            app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"
            app:cornerRadius="4dp"
            />

         </LinearLayout>
```

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
por lo tanto modifique el `Build.gradle classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` por la `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`ya que en esta versión funciona
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero ahora el problema es que el dradle project no sincroniza ya que cambie la versión, que puedo hacer para solucionar este problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si indicas cuales son los errores que te muestra podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Listo hay dejo el error que tengo.

Comment: Agrega tu clase FButton por favor, que es la que en realidad tiene el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer la versión de `Gradle` y la de tu **Android studio** deben tener coherencia. En tu `Gradle (project)`. En tu caso seria algo como :

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Ahora para "actualizar" tu AS intenta en tu menu con :

> Menu Build -> Clean Project
>
> Menu Build > Rebuild Project

Y lo otro que puedes realizar es invalidar caché y reiniciar AS.

> file -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart